# Removing a class and then reusing it

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

First, this is a greasemonkey script. I do not have access to the site from a dev perspective.

I am appending 2 buttons into a `<p>` tag. I am concentrating on the blacklist aspect.
The Refresh function runs initially to set up the buttons. When it does run, nothing on the page has the blacklist class yet. After I click a blacklist button, the .click fires the first time. At the end of the .click, I run another refresh. on the second click attempt, the .click does not fire. I am wondering if the .click gets unwired after a .remove has run. then the future blacklist buttons don't have .clicks related to them some how.

Previously, I did not need the .remove methods in the refresh method and the subsequent clicks were working.

```
    $('.blacklist').click (function(e)
   {       
       e.preventDefault();       
       var data = $(this).attr('title');      
       var blacklist = gmGet("blacklist");
       var blacklistArray = blacklist.split('|');

       blacklistArray.push(data);

       var newlist = blacklistArray.join('|');
       setTimeout(GM_setValue("blacklist",newlist),0);  

       Refresh();
       return false;
   });

function Refresh()
   {
     var Blist = GM_getValue("blacklist", "");
     var blacklistArray = Blist.split('|');
     var Wlist = GM_getValue("whitelist", "");
     var whitelistArray = Wlist.split('|');

      $('.blacklist').remove();
      $('.whitelist').remove();

      $(jQp.each(function() 
       {       
          var temp = $(this);
          var imgAlt = temp.find('img').attr('alt');

          //if blacklist array contains imgAlt then jQp.hide!
          if (imgAlt != undefined && imgAlt.substr(0, 6) != "Lineup" && imgAlt != "")
             {
               if (jQuery.inArray(imgAlt,blacklistArray) >= 0) temp.hide();
             }

          if (imgAlt != undefined && imgAlt.substr(0, 6) != "Lineup" && (jQuery.inArray(imgAlt,whitelistArray) < 0)) 
             {
                temp.append("<span style='vertical-align: top;display:inline-block;text-align:left;' class='mymenu'><input type='button' style='background-color:black;border:none;cursor:pointer;color:red;font-weight:bold;' title='" + imgAlt.replace('\'','&#39;') + "' class='blacklist' value='&#x2717;' /><br/><input type='button' style='background-color:black;border:none;cursor:pointer;margin-top:4px;color:green;font-weight:bold;' title='" + imgAlt.replace('\'','&#39;') + "' class='whitelist' value='&#x2713;' /></span>");
             } 
       }));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That code does not remove any class; it's *deleting* nodes that have the class `blacklist` or the class `whitelist`.  This also deletes any `click` handlers that those nodes have.

To get all current and future nodes with one of those classes, use [jQuery's `.on()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=on) (requires jQuery 1.7 or later).

The click function becomes:

```
$(document.body).on ("click", ".blacklist", function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault ();       
    var data = $(this).attr ('title');

    //### `gmGet` LOOKS LIKE A POSSIBLE ERROR.
    var blacklist = gmGet ("blacklist");
    var blacklistArray = blacklist.split ('|');

    blacklistArray.push (data);

    var newlist = blacklistArray.join ('|');
    setTimeout (GM_setValue ("blacklist",newlist),0);  

    Refresh ();
    return false;
} );
```